# Deploy docker registry in Jelastic

Tags: docker, docker-registry, jelastic

I wish to deploy a private Docker registry in Jelastic environment.

I've deployed the registry:2 image [from the marketplace](https://docs.jelastic.com/dockers-management#marketplace) and, once logged via ssh into the container, generated the CRT and KEY file.

I've [defined REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE and REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/deploying.md) pointing to their respective files *into* the container.

I've exposed the 5000 port through Jelastic's "endpoint" (resulting mapped to 11000)

But still when I run:

```
$ docker push node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/dockersymfony_application
The push refers to a repository [node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/dockersymfony_application] (len: 1)
unable to ping registry endpoint https://node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for , not node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it
v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/v1/_ping: x509: certificate is valid for , not node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible reasons:

1. As I see there is no Common Name (CN) in your certificate. Try to
   recreate certificate with CN.
2. Your local daemon has wrong configuration.Try [this](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/insecure.md) with info how to use self-signed certificates

As for me, I'm using option "--insecure-registry". To add it you need to edit file */etc/default/docker* on your local PC and add string (in your case): `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/`
OR `INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000'`
File also can be located at */etc/sysconfig/docker*

Comment: Ok I've got the point on certificates thank you. Still I cannot deploy ```$ docker push node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/dockersymfony_application                                                
The push refers to a repository [node4878-lrkwz-registry.jc.neen.it:11000/dockersymfony_application] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Error: Status 503 trying to push repository dockersymfony_application: "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"UNAVAILABLE\",\"message\":\"service unavailable\",\"detail\":\"health check failed: please see /debug/health\"}]}\n"```

Comment: @lrkwz , the root cause of this issue is the lack of folder "registry" in the "/var/lib/" directory. Make sure if you have this folder in the system.

Comment: ```/var/lib/registry/``` exists, contains a ```docker/``` directory and is owned by root ... and the error is somehow disappeared (?!!)

Comment: @lrkwz, the folder "registry" was created in your environment by the Jelastic team. 
FYI, since the Jelastic version 4.5 bug with creating folders from the Docker volumes will be fixed permanently. At the moment, as a workaround, you should create these folders manually.